# Load a bookmark in a sidebar in Chrome (as in Firefox)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I have long been a fan of Firefox; recently I have decided to give Chrome a try.  I am hoping that Chrome has some equivalent to loading a bookmark in a sidebar. Not the bookmarks menu, but the bookmarked page itself, like Firefox does. For example, sometimes I want my Esperanto dictionary open in the sidebar while I browse pages in Esperanto.

[image: Vortaro in sidebar with IKUE webpage]

In the screenshot, I clicked on the vortaro button on the bookmarks toolbar after visiting the IKUE webpage. Vortaro is the grey side panel and IKUE is the one with the green background.

Comment: Could you show what it looks like in Firefox?

Comment: @Oliver I had a `png` screenshot before, perhaps there were some compatibility issues. I have replaced it with a `jpg`. The grey panel labeled "Vortaro" (with the red 0 in it) is the sidebar.

Comment: I just didn't realize that there is a website being displayed in that sidebar.

Comment: @Oliver it probably wasn't obvious in the original screenshot, I included more of the browser window in this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.chromeplugins.org/google/chrome-plugins/google-tasks-sidebar-8343.html) mentions a way to do it by wrapping the bookmark url into a little JavaScript. For instance, to load http://google.com in a sidebar, add a bookmarklet with this as the URL:

`javascript:A14nH=location.href;L3f7=A14nH;R1Gh7="http://google.com";if(L3f7&&R1Gh7){Fr4Q='<frameset%20cols=\'*,*\'>\n<frame%20src=\''+L3f7+'\'/>';Fr4Q+='<frame%20src=\''+R1Gh7+'\'/>\n';Fr4Q+='</frameset>';with(document){write(Fr4Q);void(close())}}else{void(null)}`

Of course, that isn't persistent across tabs, but it's a neat thing to try out nevertheless.

Native support for a sidebar [was declined](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20785#c5), possibly delegating that to extensions. The functionality enabling extensions to do this hasn't been implemented, and at one point looked like it [never would](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30553#c6), but a proposal has been [under development](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51084) (preliminary documentation [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/sidebar-extension-api)).

[It's been suggested](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20785#c17) that the dev team is [instead focusing](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12877#c9) on the panels feature ([video demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANMrzw7JFzA#t=3m10s)), but it hasn't landed on the browser yet. There's the [Panelize extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/panelize/illfnfpoggnlapniilhkplbofldeimie) that promises to allow any page to be loaded in a panel, but as far as I know it only works in ChromeOS.

---

**TL;DR**: No, it's not possible yet, but some workarounds may do the job depending on your needs; and support for a proper sidebar (through extensions) is under development.

Comment: `en.lernu.net/cgi-bin/vortaro.pl` opens the page in full screen


`javascript:A14nH=location.href;L3f7=A14nH;R1Gh7="en.lernu.net/cgi-bin/vortaro.pl";if(L3f7&&R1Gh7){Fr4Q='<frameset%20cols=\'*,*\'>\n<frame%20src=\''+L3f7+'\'/>';Fr4Q+='<frame%20src=\''+R1Gh7+'\'/>\n';Fr4Q+='</frameset>';with(document){write(Fr4Q);void(close())}}else{void(null)}`
does not work.

Comment: Including the protocol is often helpful. Oops! I added http:// to the url in the javascript. At least it works well enough to play with now.

Comment: Sounds great, but did not work for me. It will split the window, but then I have to blank pages, instead of google at the left frame. What a pity. It would have been a good solution for me.